# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS - what version of padre should I use?

Tags: perl

I am a new, not experienced user and just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
What version of padre should I use ? Any recommended sources ?

Answer (score 1):

Install it from the repositories by

```
sudo apt-get install padre
```

It is version `1.00+dfsg-1 0`

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the 1.00 version present in the Trusty (Ubuntu 14.04) repository :

```
sudo apt-get install padre
```

Or install using Ubuntu Software center :

[image: Install via the software center]